# Using Poisson Distribution to estimate probability of an event between two numbers in R

Tags: r, probability, poisson-distribution

I have a set of data that describes the number of tunicates (marine chordates) found in different transects on the seafloor. It looks like this:

```
    tunicates<-c(13,9,7,4,5,9,5,4,5,6,8,8,6,9,9,5,8,5,6,7,14,9,3,13,9,5,8,4,5,3,6,9,3,2,10,6,8,8,6,9,12,4,19,7)
```

With a mean of 7.273. I need to calculate the probability that I will find between 3 and 6 tunicates in the next transect. In R, I tried the following:

```
    ppois(3, lambda = 7.273, lower.tail = FALSE) # = 0.931
    ppois(6, lambda = 7.273, lower.tail = TRUE) # = 0.409
    0.931-0.409 # = 0.521
```

Meaning the probability is about 52%, given the data and the mean, this seems wrong. I am thinking the actual probability should be much lower. However, I'm not sure if I am just over-thinking this or what. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: (i) Your `R` expression is incorrect: you need to subtract `ppois(2, ..., lower.tail=TRUE)` rather than `ppois(3, ..., lower.tail=FALSE)`.  (ii) Why not just compute the observed proportion of values between 3 and 6?  It can be found with `mean(tunicates >= 3 & tunicates <= 6)`.  (iii) Your data don't look Poisson: their variance is too great.

Comment: I might have worded the problem incorrectly: I'm trying to calculate the probability of having between 3 and 6 in the next transect observed, so I don't think the proportion of the data I have now would work. Are you sure about using 2 and lower.tail = TRUE for the lower value? I would think that I would need to look for 3 and greater and 6 and fewer, unless I'm misunderstanding what lower.tail does.

Comment: Your question now seems to be asking for a *prediction interval* for the proportion of future values between $3$ and $6$. If you think that the proportion in your data "won't work," then there must be some reason you think those data are irrelevant or biased or somehow wrong--but then the same reason ought to imply that your Poisson calculations are subject to the same flaws.  The fact that you refer to a transect is also interesting, because it suggests this is not a random sample.  That ought to have some bearing on the question.  You would be better off describing your problem fully.

Comment: Re the use of `ppois`.  Change `6` to a much larger number (such as `Inf`) and change `3` to `0` (or, better, `-1`).  The result ought to be close to 100%, right?  Try it out... .

Comment: Note that about 45% of your sample was between 3 and 6 (inclusive); given that the Poisson isn't a [great fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIhrb.png), some discrepancy doesn't seem too surprising. (However, I get a quite different number from 52%; somewhat smaller than your sample proportion; as whuber has been suggesting, your calculation there isn't correct -- as a first step use *`dpois`* to calculate the fitted probability of 3,4,5, and 6 and add them -- you should get something between 35 and 40%. Then try it using `ppois` but if you don't match the direct calculation, you did it wrong.)